# Change textColor of FullCalendar event Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I would like to change the textColor of an event depending on whether the "inscription" key is 0 or 1
I tested that :

```
  initCalendarEvents(): Promise<void>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let calendarApi = this.calendarComponent.getApi();

      // Index pour se positionner sur le mois proposant le prochain évènement le plus proche
      let i = 0;
      for (let university of this.universities ){
        i++;
        let event = new Event();

        event.title = university.libelle;
        event.start = university.session[0].date_session_compare;
        let extendedProps = new ExtendedProps();
        if (university.session[0].inscription.length > 0){
          extendedProps.inscription = 1;
          event.borderColor = '#7466BF';
          event.textColor = '#7466BF';
        } else {
          extendedProps.inscription = 0;
          event.borderColor = '#9D9D9C';
          event.textColor = '#9D9D9C';
        }
        extendedProps.dayStart = new Date(parseInt(university.session[0].date_session.substr(6, 4)),
            parseInt(university.session[0].date_session.substr(3, 2))-1,
            parseInt(university.session[0].date_session.substr(0, 2)));
        extendedProps.description = "à "+university.session[0].heure_debut+" au "+university.session[0].lieu_session[0].adresse;
        event.extendedProps = extendedProps;

        this.currentEvents.push(event);
        calendarApi.addEvent(event);
        if (i == 1){
          this.actualMonth = this.datePipe.transform(event.start, 'MMMM y').toUpperCase();
        }
      }
      console.log(calendarApi.getEvents());
      resolve();
    });
  }
```

But it doesn't work. Do you have an idea ?
I use Angular 9 and this is the declaration of calendarOptions :

```
  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,listWeek'
    },
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    weekends: true,
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    selectMirror: true,
    dayMaxEvents: true,
    locale: frLocale,
    select: this.handleDateSelect.bind(this),
    eventClick: this.handleEventClick.bind(this)
    eventMouseLeave: this.handleEventMouseLeave.bind(this),
    eventDidMount: (info) => {
      tippy(info.el, {
        content: info.event.title,
      })
  };
```

Thanks by advance for your help

NB : borderColor works

Comment: If you pass a static array of events to fullCalendar, it stays that way - a static copy of the list. Updating the original list (as you've tried to do) has no effect on the data held inside the calendar - because it's a copy, not a reference to the same object.

Comment: However as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular you may be able to use the "deepChangeDetection" option to make this work. See the "Modifying Properties" section of that guide.

Comment: The other alternative way to update a specific event in fullCalendar is to call https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Event-setProp

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions for the first it still doesn't work and for the second I have 'ERROR TypeError: event.setProp is not a function'', I tested that :    for (let event of this.calendarOptions.events){
      event.setProp('textColor', '#7466BF');
    }

Comment: That's because those are just plain objects, they're not fullCalendar event objects. You've misunderstood. When fullCalendar receives your raw event data, it [parses it](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing) and creates an internal object which has the data, plus all the properties and methods etc. So, first you must get the **fullCalendar** event object from the API, and then you can update it. There are some methods to get an event or events: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEvents and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEventById

Comment: P.S. in the Angular context, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular also has a section on "Calendar API" showing you how to get access the calendar API methods.

Comment: I used the API with getEvents, I succeeded to add elements, in the console the color is as I put it on the screen, however, it doesn't change

Comment: please edit the question to show exactly what you tried. Thanks.

Comment: I added my new code thanks by advance

Comment: It's worth noting that in the "month" view, the text colour is only used for "all-day" events, and the border colour is only used for timed events. However if you go to another view like timeGrid you can see it working as you are probably hoping. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, but that's what seems to be happening. I don't know if that's a bug or intentional - if you care you'd have to raise an issue with the fullCalendar maintainers and ask them (see https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs for details on how to do that)

Comment: This simple demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/abZdKLq demonstrates the behaviour I've just described. Also, the following demo is using your code above (or as close a version of it as I could make, but it's enough to reproduce your issue and show that your part of the code is basically working as it should: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/rNLxKaW . It's the fullCalendar side of things where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for your example without Angular, I try to report an eventual bug. Have a good day